# wget: Append text to default file name

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, wget

When I download a file using `wget` without the `-O` argument, it saves the file with a default name. I would like to append some text to that default name, but the `-O` option completely overrides the default name.

For example:

```
wget www.google.com  --> saves as index.html (this is the default name)
wget -O foo.html www.google.com --> saves as foo.html
```

I would like to save the file as `${default_name}_sometext.html`. For the above example, it would look something like `index_sometext.html`. Any ideas appreciated!

Edit: For those who are wondering why I might need something like this, I have scrapped thousands of URLs for a personal project, and I need to preserve the default name along with some attributes for each file.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
domain=google.com
some_text=something
lol=$(wget https://${domain} 2>&1 | grep Saving | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | sed -e's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]//g')
mv $lol ${some_text}_${lol}
```

i think it will work for you.